# Date custom filter on reactive table collection

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, filter, reactive

I have a reactive-table with custom filter defined on a date column

```
Template.displayoptions.created = function () {
    this.timeFilter = new ReactiveTable.Filter('time-filter', ['deadline']);
};

Template.displayoptions.events({
'click .form-check-input'(event,template) {
    var timefilter = template.find('#timefilter:checked').value;

    var today = new Date();
    var thisweek = new Date(moment(today).add(7, 'days'));
    var thismonth = new Date(moment(today).add(1, 'month'));

    switch(timefilter){
        case "today":
            template.timeFilter.set({"$gte": today});
            break;
        case "thisweek":
            template.timeFilter.set({"$and":[{"$gte": today}, {"$lt" : thisweek}]});
            break;
        case "thismonth":
            template.timeFilter.set({"$and":[{"$gte": today}, {"$lt" : thismonth}]});
            break;
    }        


}

});
```

When the event is triggered (radio button to select today/week/month), the table flashes but data remains unchanged.

What could be missing?

```
rowsPerPage: 5,
filters: ['time-filter'],
showNavigationRowsPerPage: false,
showFilter: false,
```

filter.get (I'm not sure if this is required)

```
Template.displayoptions.helpers({
    checked: function () {
        var istimeFilter = _.isObject(Template.instance().timeFilter.get());
        if (istimeFilter) {
            return "checked";
        } 
        return "";
    } 
});
```

radiobuttons

```
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" id="timefilter" name="timefilter" value="today" {{checked}}>
  <label class="form-check-label" for="timefilter">Today</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" id="timefilter" name="timefilter" value="thisweek" {{checked}}>
  <label class="form-check-label" for="timefilter">This Week</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" id="timefilter" name="timefilter" value="thismonth" {{checked}}>
  <label class="form-check-label" for="timefilter">This Month</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please add the part of the code that access the reactive variable using .get?

Comment: @Jankapunkt Edited my question accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still not entirely clear, but I published the entire collection on the server and then it worked with some changes -

```
'change #timefilter'(event,template) {

    template.timeFilter.set("");
    var timefilter = template.find('#timefilter:checked').value;
    var startOfDay = moment().startOf('day').toDate();
    var endOfDay = moment().endOf('day').toDate();

    var startOfWeek = moment().startOf('week').toDate();
    var endOfWeek   = moment().endOf('week').toDate();
    var startOfMonth = moment().startOf('month').toDate();
    var endOfMonth = moment().endOf('month').toDate();

    switch(timefilter){
        case "today":
            template.timeFilter.set({"$gte": startOfDay, "$lt": endOfDay});
            break;
        case "thisweek":
           template.timeFilter.set({"$gte": startOfWeek, "$lt" : endOfWeek});
            break;
        case "thismonth":
           template.timeFilter.set({"$gte": startOfMonth, "$lt" : endOfMonth});
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
```

I didn't need to use filter.get() at all.

Also, as confirmed by the author of the plugin - logical operators (and/or) do not work in custom filters